# Chance Group By clause for correct Select statement in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following 2 queries:
1)

```
SELECT *
FROM [FUNDS]     
WHERE YEAR(DATE) = 2014 AND MONTH(DATE) = 1
AND TRANSACTION_TYPE LIKE 'OT%'
AND CURRENCY != 'EUR'
AND PPC IN(1,2,3)                               
AND OC_RESID = 1 AND BNF_RESID = 2
```

Which gives me:

```
ID    TRANSACTION_TYPE     AMOUNT    OC_RESID      BNF_RESID
1      OT                  111         1              2
2      OT                  222         1              2
```

2)

```
SELECT *
FROM [FUNDS]     
WHERE YEAR(DATE) = 2014 AND MONTH(DATE) = 1
AND TRANSACTION_TYPE LIKE 'OT%'
AND CURRENCY != 'EUR'
AND PPC IN(1,2,3)                               
AND OC_RESID = 2 AND BNF_RESID = 2
```

Which gives me:

```
ID    TRANSACTION_TYPE     AMOUNT    OC_RESID      BNF_RESID
8      OT                  333         2              2
9      OT                  444         2              2
```

I want to combine them into one `SELECT` statement:

```
 SELECT 
    ISNULL((CASE WHEN OC_RESID = 1 AND BNF_RESID = 2 THEN SUM(AMOUNT) END),0) as AB,
    ISNULL((CASE WHEN OC_RESID = 2 AND BNF_RESID = 2 THEN SUM(AMOUNT) END),0) as BB
 FROM [FUNDS]     
 WHERE YEAR(DATE) = 2014 AND MONTH(DATE) = 1
 AND TRANSACTION_TYPE LIKE 'OT%'
 AND CURRENCY != 'EUR'
 AND PPC IN(1,2,3)
 GROUP BY OC_RESID, BNF_RESID
```

Here I get the two `SUM`s in separate rows:

```
AB        BB
333       0
0         777
```

But it's wrong, I need to have the result like this:

```
AB        BB
333       777
```

I think the problem is in `GROUP BY` clause, but i cannot escape it.

I would also like to escape subqueries in `SELECT` because I have lots of conditions in `WHERE` clause .

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try removing the ISNULL around your case statement?  That's why you're getting the 0 come through for each row.  Then you can probably do:

```
SELECT
 SUM(lineAB) [AB],
 SUM(lineBB) [BB]
FROM
(
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN OC_RESID = 1 AND BNF_RESID = 2 THEN SUM(AMOUNT) END as lineAB,
    CASE WHEN OC_RESID = 2 AND BNF_RESID = 2 THEN SUM(AMOUNT) END as lineBB
 FROM [FUNDS]     
 WHERE 
    YEAR(DATE) = 2014 AND MONTH(DATE) = 1
     AND TRANSACTION_TYPE LIKE 'OT%'
     AND CURRENCY != 'EUR'
     AND PPC IN(1,2,3)
 GROUP BY OC_RESID, BNF_RESID 
) tbl
```

Comment: Well,ISNULL() does not play a role here, because it just substitutes NULL with 0 in case if sums return null. Thank you, works perfect :)

Comment: You're correct too.  However, it makes it a little neater not having it there.

Answer (score 1):

Hi we can also do in this way also using union all and CTE

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
Select SUM(AMOUNT) From FUNDS a WHERE  a.OC_RESID = 1  AND a.BNF_RESID = 2 AS AA
UNION ALL
Select SUM(AMOUNT) From FUNDS b WHERE  b.OC_RESID = 2  AND b.BNF_RESID = 2 AS BB
WHERE   YEAR(DATE) = 2014 AND MONTH(DATE) = 1
     AND a.TRANSACTION_TYPE LIKE 'OT%'
     AND a.CURRENCY != 'EUR'
     AND a.PPC IN(1,2,3)
 GROUP BY a.OC_RESID, a.BNF_RESID 
 )
 Select SUM(AA),SUM(BB) FRom CTE
```